# Warning at VS startup: 'Your Azure Functions tooling installation is outdated'

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2017, azure-functions

A new message has appeared every time I start VS 2017:

> Your Azure Functions tooling installation is outdated. Please update it to the latest version.

I assume this refers to [Azure Function Tools for Visual Studio 2017](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AndrewBHall-MSFT.AzureFunctionToolsforVisualStudio2017) but I already have the latest version.

VS `Tools > Extensions and Updates` shows no updates available.

Is there really an update available, and where?

---

I am running:

- VS Pro 2017, version 15.3.0 preview 7.0
- Azure Function Tools for Visual Studio 2017, version 0.2
- Windows 7

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has been confirmed to be a bug, as there is in fact no newer version available. The team is working on a fix which should go out in the next couple days. In the meantime, please just ignore the message.

Update: Updated extension that fixes the warning is now live. You can manually update, or auto-update should push it within 1-2 days if you don't manually update.

Comment: More than one month later, with an updated VS setup, I'm getting the same message Today @david. Can I ignore it?

Comment: @GutembergRibeiro what version of the Functions extension do you have?

Comment: @DavidEbbo 0.4.30809

Comment: @GutembergRibeiro I meant the VSIX under Tools / Extensions and Updates. Latest is 15.0.30901.0 as of today.

Comment: @DavidEbbo that is the version I have for "Visual Studio 2017 Tools for Azure Functions" and was installed 9/5/2017.

Comment: @GutembergRibeiro every time you launch VS you get that message? That is certainly odd.